# Issue with Android devices having soft status bar which hides bottom tabs

Tags: android, height, statusbar, navigationbar

I am having issue with different android devices to set layout as it soft status bar at bottom covers bottom tabs.
Is there any way to overcome this issue as I tried to set margin of my tab layout which works but need a way to detect different android devices so I can set margin for particular.

[image]

[image]

Any help Appreciated.

Comment: That's strange. Are using a Fullscreen theme for your Activity?

Comment: Sorry, I am newbie in Android so don't know much.

I am using this theme:

<style name="Theme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
 </style>

Comment: Post styles and xml code, please

Comment: Are you using external library?

Comment: Below is the Layout:

What do you mean by styles and xml?


<FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:layout_height="60dip">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
    </FragmentTabHost>

It works fine on devices which doesn't have soft bottom bar but covers by Bottom bar like Motorola moto E.
I have to increase margin by 50 to show the tabs at the bottom

Comment: Hello all, Am facing same issue. Is there anyone to guide ?